# Keep DRY, but want to repeat for different reasons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, dry

So in my evolving rspecs for my RoR model, I ended up with two tests exactly the same:

```
it 'is valid when x is zero' do
    foo = build(:foo, x: 0, y: 10)
    expect(foo.valid?).to be_truthy
end
it 'is valid when y is ten' do
    foo = build(:foo, x: 0, y: 10)
    expect(foo.valid?).to be_truthy
end
```

This came about because I wrote the spec for validating x first, then added the spec for y after.

Obviously, time to refactor.  I could delete one of the specs because they're duplicates: keep it DRY.

Now, the internals of each spec may be exactly the same, but the `it` descriptions are different. I don't want to lose the information contained there.

My questions is - is it acceptable in this case to keep the duplicates specs intact, or should I 'merge' them and reword the `it` description? Perhaps:

```
it 'is valid when x is zero and y is ten' do
    foo = build(:foo, x: 0, y: 10)
    expect(foo.valid?).to be_truthy
end
```

But to my mind, I now have one spec that is testing two things (the two validate clauses in the Foo model). That's not good, either. There's a smell lurking.

Is there another approach I've missed?

Comment: Totally acceptable to have both tests IMHO

Comment: It depends. Should the first test pass with `y: nil`? with `y: false`? with `y: MyY.new`? If not, you are already in troubles. One should desire, what is being tested. I would go with 4 tests for `{x, y} ∈ [good, bad]`.

Comment: Why test that `valid?` is truthy when you can use [`#be_valid`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/RSpec%2FRails%2FMatchers%3Abe_valid) e.g. `expect(foo).to be_valid` the idea is exactly the same and makes it more readable in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would worry less about DRY and more about writing specs that actually cover the behavior you intend to.

```
it 'is valid when x is zero' do
  foo = build(:foo, x: 0)
  expect(foo.valid?).to be_truthy
end
```

This example actually does not cover your validation at all! If you comment out the validation in your model it will still pass.

Some tips when testing model validations:

- Avoid using factories. Just initialize with `.new` and the attribute under test.
- Test for both invalid and valid input.
- Describe the behavior of the validation - not which values are acceptable.
- Test each validation in isolation - your integration and functional specs will usually cover the validations as a whole.

---

```
RSpec.describe Foo do
  describe "validations" do
    describe 'x' do
      it "validates that x is a number between 1 and 10" do
        expect(Foo.new(500).valid?.errors[:x]).to include "must be less than or equal to 10".
        expect(Foo.new(10).valid?.errors).to_not have_key :x
      end
    end

    describe 'y' do
      it "validates that y is a number that is less than 15" do
        expect(Foo.new(500).valid?.errors[:y]).to include "must be less than 15".
        expect(Foo.new(10).valid?.errors).to_not have_key :y
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you then want to dry it out have a look at `shoulda-matchers` which makes this far more fluent.

Comment: Ah, interesting - I was always focussing on checking for a valid record. Hence, when I later added field `y` I had to keep the record valid, thus adding `y` to older tests.  I can see in your examples Each one focuses on just the field it's testing without having to worry about others.

Comment: I prefer this answer because my tests remain DRY and I can see I wasn't focussing on testing the right thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Generally, I think that having small independent tests is more important than being DRY.

However, there appears to be an inconsistency in the logic of your tests.

If foo is *always* valid when x is zero, then you should be able to drop the y value in the first spec.

```
it 'is valid when x is zero' do
  foo = build(:foo, x: 0)
  expect(foo.valid?).to be_truthy
end
```

And if foo *always* valid when y is ten then you should be able to drop the x value in that spec.

```
it 'is valid when y is ten' do
  foo = build(:foo, y: 10)
  expect(foo.valid?).to be_truthy
end
```

---

If this is not the case, you might consider testing the cases more specifically.

For example:

```
it 'allows x to equal zero' do
  foo = build(:foo, x: 0)
  foo.valid?
  expect(foo.errors).to_not have_key(:x)
end

it 'allows y to be ten' do
  foo = build(:foo, y: 10)
  foo.valid?
  expect(foo.errors).to_not have_key(:y)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are cases where its ok to keep duplicate tests.

The rules behind the practice of DRY code are not hard and fast, its more of a heuristic. One of the main purpose of keeping code DRY is primarily for maintenance purposes. Sometime people (myself included) feel that you are trying to ensure that you are not repeating yourself anywhere just for the sake of not repeating yourself. If you find that you are adding undue complexity for sake of only writing something once (I like the saying from Sandy Metz “Not so DRY it chafes”) then you need to ask yourself “Is this really worth the effort?” “Does this make my code anymore readable or maintainable?”. One test that I think think is a good litmus is weither or not the instances of duplicate code you wrote were written for different reasons, like this instance is for the side effect this instance is for the result.

Comment: There's another one, I think by Jay Fields: "Tests (and DSLs) should be DAMP, not DRY (Descriptive And Meaningful Phrases)".

Comment: Hmm that is very helpful advice, test are for more than just preventing regressions and keeping your code decoupled, they also should serve as documentation. I will keep DAMP in mind.